# Bash getopt to accept multiple parameters

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing a script using getopt to parse parameters. The solution I have so far only accepts one parameter. Is there a way to make this solution accept multiple parameters (eg. both '-f and -l)?

solution in link does not work for me.
[Bash getopt accepting multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563365/bash-getopt-accepting-multiple-parameters)

code:
'''

```
while getopts "f:l:" option; do
      case "${option}" in
          f) firstdate=${OPTARG}
             shift
             ;;
          l) lastdate=${OPTORG}
             ;;
         *)
            echo "UsageInfo"
            exit 1
            ;;
       esac
      shift
    done
```

'''

Comment: Remove the `shift`s inside the loop. If you want to remove the option arguments after they've been processed, add `shift $((OPTIND-1))` *after* the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a typo: `OPTORG` should be `OPTARG`.

More importantly, you don't need the calls to `shift`. `getopts` takes care of consuming and skipping over each option and argument.

```
while getopts "f:l:" option; do
  case "${option}" in
      f) firstdate=${OPTARG} ;;
      l) lastdate=${OPTARG} ;;
      *)
        echo "UsageInfo"
        exit 1
        ;;
   esac
done
```